# how to enable native memory tracking in a windows service which reads java options from registry and create a JVM?

Tags: java, windows, memory, native, taskmanager

We have a windows service which reads java_options from registry and create a custom JVM within which it runs the java part. Although, we have not encountered yet any out of memory error, but our long running app seems to cross the specified memory limit (which we expect it to run with). however , lately we have been coming across problems reported from production that there has had been memory violations.

In order to find where exactly can we reduce the memory footprints for our application, we need to be able to enable NativeMemoryTracking in our application. since we are creating a custom jvm, explicitly use of -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary does not seem to help. even after adding it, it does not display native memory breakdown for our windows service .it fails with a message native tracking is not enabled.

here is how we are creating a custom jvm in the below code snippet.since i have already tested that it can sccessfully read other vm args like -Xmx or -Xmn from java_options in our application, i hoped that it would be able to read -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary too. but i am clueless as to why its not taking NMT but can take other vm args.

```
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 


    vm_args.version = 0x00010002; 
    vm_args.options = options; 
    vm_args.nOptions = optionCounter; 
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE; 

           /* Create the Java VM */ 
    Debug(_T("[ENV] Going to create JVM"));


    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&m_pJvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

i expect that with the use of XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary , i must be able to get summary breakdown of memory usage of my windows service in order to dive into the memory region whose memory can be targeted to be reduced.

but i get to see Native memory trackng is not enabled message when i run JCMD with the process id of my service.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am experiencing the same situation. I have tested also to connect to the service with the user, whcih runs the service, but then I get the IOException  "Acces is denied"